# Migrate to reactJS 16 clicking on Link does not update view

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have this app.js:

```
import { Route, BrowserRouter, Switch, HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { env } from 'config'
const Router = env === 'dev' ? HashRouter : BrowserRouter

let store = createStore(rootReducer,
    compose(
        applyMiddleware(thunk),
        window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f
    )
)
<Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
        <Switch>
            <Route name="aboutus" path="/aboutus" component={AboutUsContainer}/>
            <Route name="home" path="/" component={HomePageContainer}/>
        </Switch>
    </Router>
</Provider>
```

And in the AboutusContainer, I have:

```
// other imports
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

class AboutUsContainer extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div id="aboutus">{this.props.text}</div>
        )
    }
}

function select(state) {
    return {
        text: state.aboutUsText,
    }
}

export default withRouter(connect(select)(AboutUsContainer))
```

In HomePageContainer:

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

class HomePageContainer extends BaseComponent {

    render() {
        return (
            <HomePageContent content={this.props.text}/>
        )
    }
}

function select(state) {
    return {
        text: state.homePageText,
    }
}

export default withRouter(connect(select)(HomePageContainer))
```

And in HomePageContent, it is:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

export default class HomePageContent extends Component {
    render() {
        return <Link to='/aboutus'>{this.props.content}</Link>
    }
}
```

and if I click on the link on HomePageContent, I see the url is changed to /#/aboutus, but the page component is not updated and is still on old page. Clicking on the same Link again will give:

```
Warning: Hash history cannot PUSH the same path; a new entry will not be added to the history stack
```

Which confirms that the app indeed recognized the the location to be the expected location.

I am using react-router-dom@4.3.1

The other question suggested using withRouter but I have done that. What did I miss?

Comment: Are you importing Link in your second file and importing AboutUsContainer in the first one ?

Comment: @Ivo Yes, imports are done properly. Link is imported from react-router-dom.

Answer (score 0):

I created a simplified version of the routing with dummy store and works like a charm with both routers.

**reducers.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";

const fooReducer = function foo(state = { foo: "about" }) {
  return state;
};

const reducers = combineReducers({
  fooReducer
});

export default reducers;
```

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Route, BrowserRouter, Switch, HashRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import reducers from "./reducers";

import AboutUs from "./AboutUs";
import HomePageContainer from "./HomePageContainer";

const store = createStore(reducers);

function App({ router: Router }) {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route name="aboutus" path="/aboutus" component={AboutUs} />
          <Route name="home" path="/" component={HomePageContainer} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App router={BrowserRouter} />, rootElement);
```

**HomePageContainer.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux"; // +
import HomePageContent from "./HomePageContent";

class HomePageContainer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <HomePageContent content={this.props.foo} />;
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ // +
  foo: state.fooReducer.foo         // +
});                                 // +

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(HomePageContainer); // +
```

**HomePageContent.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default class HomePageContent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Link to="/aboutus">{this.props.content}</Link>;
  }
}
```

**AboutUs.js**

```
export default () => "aboutUs";
```

*You can switch between routers in the example in `<App router={BrowserRouter} />` line.* Try to extend my code and I hope it will work.

Comment: Thanks @gazdagergo. I would have to use redux though. What's the solution with redux?

Comment: I added the redux part in my example. I marked with `// +` the redux related lines, and I added the `reducers.js`

Comment: How does the redux state connects with the component now as you don't have that in the container any more?

Comment: I edited again my example:  added the `connect` to the container. The `withRouter` was not necessary so I removed it., see the `// +`- es for the edited lines.